# How to set `wxTL_3STATE` checkbox read only in `wxTreeListCtrl?`

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using `wxTL_3STATE` flag for `wxTreeListCtrl`, I need to set some checkboxes to `undefined state` and they should be read only. User should not be able to edit the state of checkbox. How can I do this? How should I disable these records for user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the control with `wxTL_3STATE` flag, but without the `wxTL_USER_3STATE` one, see [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_tree_list_ctrl.html).

Comment: yes, I am using `wxTL_3STATE` flag without `wxTL_USER_3STATE`, I want to set checkbox state programmatically and user should not be able to change that state. But here user can edit checkbox state. I want to disable some checkboxes of tree. How should I do this?

Comment: Without `wxTL_USER_3STATE` the user shouldn't be able to set the checkbox to the 3rd state but, indeed, it's still possible to check or uncheck it. Having completely read-only checkboxes is not supported currently in this control.